# Python Pandas: Apply method to column if condition met in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like the following:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["B","X"],["C","Y"],["D","X"]])
>>> df.columns = ["A","B"]
>>> df
   A  B
0  B  X
1  C  Y
2  D  X
```

How can I apply a method to change the values of column A only if the value in column B is "X"? The desired outcome for example might be:

```
>>> df
    A  B
0  Bx  X
1   C  Y
2  Dx  X
```

I thought of combining the two columns together (`df['C']=df['A']+df['B']`) but probably there's a better way to perform such a simple operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is using loc

```
df.loc[df.B == 'X', 'A']+='x'

    A   B
0   Bx  X
1   C   Y
2   Dx  X
```

EDIT: Based on the question in the comment, is this what you are looking for?

df.loc[df.B == 'X', 'A'] = df.A.str.lower()+'x'

```
    A   B
0   bx  X
1   C   Y
2   dx  X
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply. This works for this example, but what if I had a more complicated function where I had to apply a method instead? Something like `df.loc[df.B == 'X', 'A'].apply(method)`  would be good

Comment: It would be easier if you give an indicative example of the function you intend to apply

Comment: Specifically, I'm looking at replacing characters and changing characters to lower case, like so: `def method(word): return word.replace("/","").lower() + " x"`

Comment: Thats what I'm looking for! Thank you so much!